# Validating Facebook and Twitter URL using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

In my application I am using jquery validation for forms.

There are two other fileds to enter the twitter page url and facebook page url.

How can I validate these url using jquery?

Examples:

```
http://twitter.com/anypage

http://twitter.com/#!/anypage

http://facebook.com/anypage
```

Comment: What criteria you want to validate? Like: Is it valid url, required field or whatever

Comment: Why don't you just ask for a username instead of a URL?

Comment: not required validation i meaned url validation and the url must be the twitter page and facebook page

Answer (score 13):

None of the above solutions/regular expressions are flexible enough.
Check my [*code*](http://jsfiddle.net/36Wct/11/) in jsFiddle.

---

```
var str1 = 'http://twitter.com/anypage';    //True
var str2 = 'http://twitter.com/#!/anypage'; //True


var str3 = 'http://facebook2.com/anypage'; //False

var str4 = 'http://www.facebook.com/anypage';  //True http & www
var str5 = 'http://facebook.com/anypage';      //True http 
var str6 = 'https://facebook.com/anypage';     //True https 
var str7 = 'https://www.facebook.com/anypage'; //True https & www

var str8 = 'facebook.com/anypage';             //True no protocol
var str9 = 'www.facebook.com/anypage';         //True no protocol & www



function validate_url(url)
{
  if (/^(https?:\/\/)?((w{3}\.)?)twitter\.com\/(#!\/)?[a-z0-9_]+$/i.test(url))
     return 'twitter';    

 if (/^(https?:\/\/)?((w{3}\.)?)facebook.com\/.*/i.test(url))
     return 'facebook';

 return 'unknown';
}

alert('This link is ' + validate_url(str2));​
```

Comment: This will also match the top facebook url - without any page `(/^(https?:\/\/)?((w{3}\.)?)facebook\.com\/*.*/i`

Answer (score 2):

I think this may help you

```
function validFBurl(enteredURL) {
  var FBurl = /^(http|https)\:\/\/www.facebook.com\/.*/i;
  if(!enteredURL.match(FBurl)) {
      alert("This is not a Facebook URL");
      }
  else {
      alert("This IS a Facebook URL");
      }
  }
```

For Twitter just add new var for Twitter URL

```
var TWurl = /^(http|https)\:\/\/(www.|)twitter.com\/.*/i;
```

Validate:

1. http://twitter.com/username > TRUE
2. https://twitter.com/username > TRUE
3. http://www.twitter.com/username > TRUE
4. https://www.twitter.com/username > TRUE

Source:
http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=247621

Comment: You can just write `https?`.  Also, you should validate the username portion (path) too

Comment: i also need twitter page url validation like this

Comment: @SLaks nt all people login from https. I am from mexico and some people don't know what is that and then connect from normal http.

Comment: @MasUser just substitute Facebook.com to twitter.com in another function or the same

Comment: @Ernesto: You can still write `https?`.  `?` means optional.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
var str1 = 'http://twitter.com/anypage';
var str2 = 'http://twitter.com/#!/anypage';
var str3 = 'http://facebook.com/anypage';

if (/https?:\/\/twitter\.com\/(#!\/)?[a-z0-9_]+$/i.test(str1))
    alert('Str1 has passed first regexp');

if (/https?:\/\/twitter\.com\/(#!\/)?[a-z0-9_]+$/i.test(str2))
    alert('Str2 has passed first regexp');

if (/https?:\/\/facebook\.com\/[a-z0-9_]+$/i.test(str3))
    alert('Str3 has passed second regexp');
```

Or a validation function http://jsfiddle.net/36Wct/2/

```
var str1 = 'http://twitter.com/anypage';
var str2 = 'http://twitter.com/#!/anypage';
var str3 = 'http://facebook.com/anypage';
var str4 = 'http://facebook2.com/anypage';


function validate_url(url)
{
  if (/https?:\/\/twitter\.com\/(#!\/)?[a-z0-9_]+$/i.test(url))
     return 'twitter';    

 if (/https?:\/\/facebook\.com\/[a-z0-9_]+$/i.test(url))
     return 'facebook';

 return 'unknown';
}

alert('This link is ' + validate_url(str4));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`url()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/url) method from the `jQuery Validation` plugin. It checks if the entered url is valid. You can still customize it upon your requirement (which is to check if the page belongs to twitter or FB).

Source: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation